# EF + AutoFac | Navigation properties are not getting reloaded/refreshed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, autofac

Following is my code:

```
Entity.Invoice inStoreInvoice = invoiceRepository.Find(x => x.AccountId == accountId && x.CompanyId == companyId && x.Id == invoiceNum);
if (inStoreInvoice.CustomerMaster.SomeId == null)
{
    // External code which updates the CustomerMaster with SomeId value.
    // ..... 
    // .....
    // Now I want to reload inStoreInvoice with updated value of CustomerMaster.SomeId
    inStoreInvoice = invoiceRepository.Find(x => x.AccountId == accountId && x.CompanyId == companyId && x.Id == invoiceNum);
}
string value = inStoreInvoice.CustomerMaster.SomeId; // This gives me null..!!
```

Code seems self-explanatory (let me know if you need me to elaborate on any point). The invoiceRepository.Find() internally calls dbset.FirstOrDefault() .. i.e. get the first entity from the list which matches the query expression. CustomerMaster is the navigation property for Invoice entity

My question is, why the statement,

```
string value = inStoreInvoice.CustomerMaster.SomeId; // This gives me null..!!
```

gives a null value?! I tried below options but did not work, same result (entity is the inStoreInvoice object which I am passing).

```
1. context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
2. context.Entry(entity).Reload();
3. ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.Detach(entity);
4. ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, entity);
```

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try to include the navigation property: .Include(x => x.CustomerMaster)

Comment: There are multiple other navigation properties which I want to reload similar to CustomerMaster. I was hoping to avoid such statements for each navigation property and reload the object completely in one go.

Comment: Then you should enable LazyLoading in your DbContext configuration.

Comment: All my navigation properties are virtual. I have enabled LazyLoading. I don't want to use .Include and want all my navigation properties to be lazily loaded (which is currently right now).